# Name and size from NSFont

Tags: nsstring, nsfontpanel, nsfont, nsfontmanager

i've tried to find something in the Internet, but right now I don't have an answer, so it would be great if you can help me!
So far I have a NSFont object, but I would like the name (as NSString) and size of the font, so I can output that! It's like

```
[NSFont fontWithName:@"Menlo" size:11];
```

only backwards, so I get the name "Menlo" and as size 11.

Thanks for help!
Xcoder from Germany

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The name and size of NSFont are variables with setters and getters (`@property`) so you can easily get them:

```
object.fontName;
object.systemSize;
```

Comment: Are you sure that NSFont really have a property with name systemSize? It doesn't work at all in 10.6 SDK.  @JPed's answer works for me.

Comment: systemSize do not exist. At least not anymore.

Answer (score 13):

```
NSString* fontName = [*yourfont* fontName];
float fontSize = [[[*yourfont* fontDescriptor] objectForKey:NSFontSizeAttribute] floatValue];
```

Answer (score 7):

I think it's font.pointSize now, not font.systemSize.

Answer (score 0):

Fonts are just objects. They have variables like `fontName` and `systemSize`. 
For example if I wanted to know the font and size of a UILabel named titleLabel I would use:

`NSLog(@"fontwithName:%@ size:%f", self.titleLabel.font.fontName, self.titleLabel.font.systemSize);`

For more look at the NSFont Class Reference.
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSFont_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Even the documentation linked above does not mention a systemSize property. The correct property is pointSize.