# Check if NSFont is bold in Swift

Tags: swift, nsfont

I am writting unit test checking the format of a generated *NSAttributedString*.

I can extract the font like this:

```
if let font = attributedString.attributesAtIndex(0, effectiveRange: nil) as? NSFont {
    ...
}
```

Given this *NSFont* instance, how can I check if it is bold or not?

Comment: Please check this it could help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9234587/name-and-size-from-nsfont

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can check your font traits like this:

```
let descriptor = font.fontDescriptor
let symTraits = descriptor.symbolicTraits
let traitSet = NSFontTraitMask(rawValue: UInt(symTraits))
let isBold = traitSet.contains(.BoldFontMask))
```

But I'm not sure if `isBold` would be `true` for all seemingly-bold fonts.

Answer (score 3):

Updated answer for **Swift 4** and with an `NSFont` extension:

```
extension NSFont {
    var isBold: Bool {
        return fontDescriptor.symbolicTraits.contains(.bold)
    }
}
```